# Getting invalid runtime for javaSE-16 error in vscode - runtime not compatible with the javaSE-16 environment

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, java-16

i recently changed my distro to `arch` from `manjaro` which comes installed with `openjdk`, the problem with that is i couldn't read the java developer code (like for example, I want to read how `Queue` is implemented - couldn't do it with `openjdk` for some reason), so i installed oracle `jdk-16` which solved the problem - i could now `ctrl + leftclick` on some entity and view its implementation. But that posed a new problem, when ever i start `vscode` it shows me this error

```
Invalid runtime for JavaSE-16: Runtime at '/usr/lib/jvm/java-16-jdk' is not compatible with 
the 'JavaSE-16' environment.
```

I tried every other value for `runtime path` in the `java:configure java runtime` but I end up getting the same problem but with different `runtime path`.

I even changed my default java in my os using `archlinux-java set java-16-jdk` and checked it if it was set correctly using `archlinux-java status` and it says `java-16-jdk` is the default jdk.

Here, is my the relevant part of `settings.json` -

```
"java.configuration.runtimes": [
    
        {
            "name": "JavaSE-16",
            "path": "/usr/lib/jvm/java-16-jdk",
            "default": true
        }
    ],
    "java.home": "/usr/lib/jvm/java-16-jdk"
```

Also when i hover over the name attribute of java.configuration.runtime i get this following hint -

```
Value is not accepted. Valid values: "J2SE-1.5", "JavaSE-1.6", "JavaSE-1.7", "JavaSE-1.8", 
"JavaSE-9", "JavaSE-10", "JavaSE-11", "JavaSE-12", "JavaSE-13", "JavaSE-14", "JavaSE-15
```

I'm kinda new to java, so any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: The messages are quite self-explanatory. You might have to seek what software upgrades would bring compatibility with the JDK version you are using. Until then stick to your existing version or the one amongst those supported.

Answer (score 0):

There's github issue for reporting [java extension doesn't support java16,](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/1879) so engineers are [adding support for java16](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/pull/1836). It may be achievable in next update.

Comment: @turingman. Now jdk16 is achievable in latest java extension.